# can python numpy poission generate a float?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to generate poission instances with the numpy library:

```
arrayVal = np.random.poisson(lambda_,k)
```

but it only generate me a array of type Int.

is there a way in numpy to **return a float array instead**?

Thanks,
Guy.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `np.random.poisson(lambda,k)` generates a syntax error here.

Comment: lambda and k are parameters, np is the import of numpy library

Comment: `lambda` is a keyword, it can't be used as identifier. Your actual code may be using `lambda_` or `l` or something.

Comment: what are you trying to do?  I think you misunderstand how `np.random.poisson` functions.

Comment: Create an array of generate from the poission distribute,to use it later to a simulator that i'm building..

Comment: The [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) (for a given `lambda_` value) has nonnegative *integer* values.  Are you sure you want samples from a Poisson distribution?  Can you provide more information on what you need?

Comment: `poisson(k, size=N)` will give you a random sample of nonnegative integers with sample size `N` drawn from a poisson distribution with `mean=variance=k`. The only floats involved are the probabilities associated with the outcomes, not the outcomes themselves.

Comment: my purpose is to create instances with inter-arrival time of poission distributions with some lambda_ .

Comment: So if i understand your suggestion is to build it with exponential with lambda_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is often used to model *the number of events* that happen in a fixed amount of time. The number of events is always an integer. The Poisson distribution is a discrete distribution.

The [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) is used model the *amount of time* between events in a Poisson process. The amount of time is a float, and the exponential is a continuous distribution. It sounds like what you want is an exponential distribution, not a Poisson distribution.

```
In [129]: np.random.exponential(5, size=10)
Out[129]: 
array([ 5.88816461,  2.41700899,  0.70106326,  2.29108557,  0.08888838,
        7.88830053,  3.30970463,  4.23713366,  9.96793111,  3.02695017])
```